# Making an NSImage out of an NSView

Tags: cocoa, nsview, nsimage

I know how to create an `NSImage` depicting an `NSView` and all its subviews, but what I'm after is an `NSImage` of a view **ignoring** its subviews. I can think of ways of doing this with a subclass of `NSView`, but I'm keen to avoid subclassing if possible. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You could temporarily remove the subviews, create the image, and put the subviews back. That used to be simple, but now with auto layout it's a problem, because removing the subviews also removes any constraints which reference them.

Comment: I'd be doing this in an app designed to help me troubleshoot other apps, so the performance hit associated with removing then re-adding constraints isn't really a big deal - the priority is an approach that can be applied to any view hierarchy. If this remove-then-reinstall approach can be done reliably for any view it could be the way to go - I'll see how far I get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hide the subviews, grab the image, unhide the subviews:

```
NSMutableArray* hiddenViews = [[NSMutableArray] alloc init];

for (NSView* subview in [self subviews]) {
    if (subview hidden) [hiddenViews addObject: subview];
    else [subview setHidden:YES];
}

NSSize imgSize = self.bounds.size;
NSBitmapImageRep * bir = [self bitmapImageRepForCachingDisplayInRect:[self bounds]];
[bir setSize:imgSize];
[self cacheDisplayInRect:[self bounds] toBitmapImageRep:bir];
NSImage* image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:imgSize];
[image addRepresentation:bir];

for (NSView* subview in [self subviews]) {
    if (![hiddenViews containsObject: subview])
        [subview setHidden:NO];
}
```

Comment: You should check for subviews which are already hidden and don't unhide them at the end.

Comment: Thank you, code edited to retain the state of previously hidden subviews.

Comment: That's a great suggestion - so simple, and yet it would probably have never occurred to me!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest making a copy of the desired NSView offscreen and taking a snapshot of that.